# Issue getting django celery worker started on elastic-beanstalk

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-celery

I am trying to get my celery worker running on elastic-beanstalk. It works fine locally but when I deploy to EB I get the error "Activity execution failed, because: /usr/bin/env: bash": No such file or directory". I am pretty novice at celery and EB so I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

I am working on a windows machine and I have seen other people face this issue with windows and fix it by converting "celery_configuration.txt" file to UNIX EOL, however I am using celery-worker.sh instead but I converted it to a UNIX EOL which still didn't work.

.ebextensions/celery.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    libcurl-devel: []

container_commands:
    01_mkdir_for_log_and_pid:
        command: "mkdir -p /var/log/celery/ /var/run/celery/"
    02_celery_configure:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/celery-worker.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/ && chmod 744 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/celery-worker.sh"
        cwd: "/opt/python/ondeck/app"
    03_celery_run:
        command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/celery-worker.sh"
```

.ebextensions/celery-worker.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get django environment variables
celeryenv=`cat /opt/python/current/env | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/export //g' | sed 's/$PATH/%(ENV_PATH)s/g' | sed 's/$PYTHONPATH//g' | sed 's/$LD_LIBRARY_PATH//g'`
celeryenv=${celeryenv%?}

# Create celery configuraiton script
celeryconf="[program:celeryd-worker]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A backend -P solo --loglevel=INFO -n worker.%%h

directory=/opt/python/current/app/enq_web
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998

environment=$celeryenv
"

# Create the celery supervisord conf script
echo "$celeryconf" | tee /opt/python/etc/celery.conf

# Add configuration script to supervisord conf (if not there already)
if ! grep -Fxq "[include]" /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  then
  echo "[include]" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
  echo "files: celery.conf" | tee -a /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
fi

# Reread the supervisord config
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread

# Update supervisord in cache without restarting all services
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update

# Start/Restart celeryd through supervisord
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf restart celeryd-worker
```

I'm sure its something simple I missed but I have spent hours looking everywhere for a solution and at this point i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your shebang (the `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) line in your celery-worker.sh file try using either `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`.  Where bash or sh live will depend a lot on which AMI you are using with beanstalk.

Comment: It turned out that it was because I needed to convert it to Unix EOL but when I added the new file git was converting it back to Windows EOL and thats what was causing the problem.